# Force is.unsorted() to false

Tags: r, arrays, sorting, dataframe, rstudio

I have a dataframe object that is presorted, and I am trying to call a function that requires it to be sorted. Somehow is.unsorted() is returning true. R then proceeds to sort it.

Unfortunately, there are about 2million entries, and I don't have the memory. Is there a way to force is.unsorted to be false?

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you're using `is.unsorted`? You mention a `dataframe` but `is.unsorted` is not documented work on `data.frames`, but vectors. A small mock data set would be helpful here (even if it can't reproduce the offputting behavior you're encountering, to get an idea of the structure of your problem/what you've tried it will go a long way)

Comment: I don't think it is event possible to define what "sorted" means for a data frame as there are many ways to sort a data frame (one has to provide a list of columns).

Answer (score 1):

Quick check of the RDocumentation ([is.unsorted](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.1/topics/is.unsorted)) includes the following line:

> Note:
>   This function is designed for objects with one-dimensional indices, as described above. Data frames, matrices and other arrays may give surprising results.

Therefore, you should avoid using this function on complete data frames. Instead, you should run this function on certain features of the data frame, instead of the entire data frame itself.

Take the below code snippet for example. You can see that this function works as expected on one-dimensional objects (vectors); however has a surprising  result when run on a data frame (returned `FALSE` when expecting `TRUE` result).

However, when the data frame was subset (using the `$` operator) and the `is.unsorted()` function is run on the individual features, then it returns the expected result.

```
> vec <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
> is.unsorted(vec)  # Expected: FALSE
[1] FALSE

> vec <- c(1,3,2,5,4)
> is.unsorted(vec)  # Expected: TRUE
[1] TRUE

> vec <- c("A","B","C","D","E")
> is.unsorted(vec)  # Expected: FALSE
[1] FALSE

> vec <- c("A","C","B","E","D")
> is.unsorted(vec)  # Expected: TRUE
[1] TRUE

> dat <- data.frame(num=c(1,2,3,4,5)
+                  ,chr=c("A","B","C","D","E")
+                  ,stringsAsFactors=FALSE
+                  )
> is.unsorted(dat)  # Expected: FALSE
[1] FALSE

> dat <- data.frame(num=c(1,3,2,5,4)
+                  ,chr=c("A","B","C","D","E")
+                  ,stringsAsFactors=FALSE
+                  )
> is.unsorted(dat)  # Expected: TRUE
[1] FALSE

> is.unsorted(dat$num)  # Expected: TRUE
[1] TRUE

> is.unsorted(dat$chr)  # Expected: FALSE
[1] FALSE
```